# Object return initial value when starting app

Tags: javascript, node.js

when my app starts app, one of my variables returns inital value. Here is my code

routes.js

```
router.post("/build-envEP", (req, res, next) => {
    consts.setNewConst("env", req.body.env);
    console.log(consts.getConsts().env); // returns what I expect
    res.status(201).type('application/xml').send(operations.xml);
});
```

constants.js

```
var consts = {};

module.exports.setNewConst = function(key, value){
    return consts[key] = value;
}

module.exports.getConsts = function(){
    return consts;
}
```

builder.js

```
...

console.log(consts.getConsts().env)

...
```

When I start my server, I got `{}`.

Here my console output:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
undefined
```

Sometimes I'm getting `undefined`, sometimes I got `{}`

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How can i get the result that I set with ‘setNewConst’?

Comment: Kerem, could you please share you app code where you add routes to your express app?